# How to call a function multiple times?

Tags: javascript

I'm running a code where I must create a function and call it multiple times. I am having trouble calling it more than once. how can i solve this? im writing in javascript. So I create a function called beCheerful(); within it must be a string 'good morning!' called 98 times. Please help. It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: One way is calling it from inside a `for` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function beCheerful() {
    console.log('good morning');
}

for (var i = 0; i < 98; i++) {
    beCheerful();
}
```

This will loop from 0 to 97, calling beCheerful each time.  There are a few types of loops:  for, while, do-while, forEach... in Javascript.  You should read up on them.

Comment: function beCheerful();

var hello = 'good morning!';

for(var i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    beCheerful(hello);
}
okay so this is my code so far and its telling me i have syntax error. Help please!

Comment: I updated the answer to show you the proper syntax for the function.  If you like this answer, please accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure if there has been any changes to Javascript, but my function does not run more than twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can try lodash https://lodash.com/docs#times:

```
_.times(98, beCheerful);
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using an external library when the OP is learning the real basis of the language? (and of CS in general)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this code is not any better than the accepted answer, but it is shorter pretty much:

```js
Array(98).fill(1).forEach(()=>{
    beCheerful();
})
```

It works by creating a list of 98 ones, and for each one, running your cheerful function once.

Comment: I like this one, but there seems to be a missing back parenthesis in the end.